# How to declare a variable as thread local portably?

Tags: c, gcc, portability, c11, thread-local-storage

C11 introduces the `_Thread_local` storage class specifier that can be used in combination with the `static` and `extern` storage class specifiers to declare a variable as thread local. The GNU C compiler suite implements a storage class specifier `__thread` with the same same semantics.

Unfortunately I did not find any compiler (I tried gcc, clang and SUN studio) that actually implements the `_Thread_local` keywords. I currently use the following construct to declare a keyword `thread_local`:

```
/* gcc doesn't know _Thread_local from C11 yet */
#ifdef __GNUC__
# define thread_local __thread
#elif __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L
# define thread_local _Thread_local
#else
# error Don't know how to define thread_local
#endif
```

I know that this probably does not work with MSVC and other compilers. Can anybody suggest me a better method to declare `thread_local` in a way that it works in as many compilers as possible?

### Edit

[Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48015/christoph) suggested that Microsoft Visual C allows `__declspec(thread)`. This is the updated macro definition:

```
/* gcc doesn't know _Thread_local from C11 yet */
#ifdef __GNUC__
# define thread_local __thread
#elif __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L
# define thread_local _Thread_local
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
# define thread_local __declspec(thread)
#else
# error Cannot define thread_local
#endif
```

Comment: in MSVC, it's written as `__declspec( thread )` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ax54352.aspx)

Comment: @KingsIndian Jupp. That's why I asked what the best way to define this macro is.

Comment: @KingsIndian Generic may include a bunch of special cases for stupid compilers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Combining [information from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage#C.2B.2B) with this [list of compiler macros](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/), I came up with the following (untested) version:

```
#ifndef thread_local
# if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112 && !defined __STDC_NO_THREADS__
#  define thread_local _Thread_local
# elif defined _WIN32 && ( \
       defined _MSC_VER || \
       defined __ICL || \
       defined __DMC__ || \
       defined __BORLANDC__ )
#  define thread_local __declspec(thread) 
/* note that ICC (linux) and Clang are covered by __GNUC__ */
# elif defined __GNUC__ || \
       defined __SUNPRO_C || \
       defined __xlC__
#  define thread_local __thread
# else
#  error "Cannot define thread_local"
# endif
#endif
```

Comment: Hey that's nice. Thank you very much!