# Redundant __thread and omp threadlocal declaration

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp, portability

I am trying to write some library code that may be used by people who have pthreads enabled (or not), and by people who have openmp support (or not). I have some variable that I really want to be in thread-local storage. Is there any potential harm in specifying this twice, for example

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
# define PREFIX __thread
#elif __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L
# define PREFIX _Thread_local
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
# define PREFIX __declspec(thread)
#else
# define PREFIX
#endif

PREFIX int var = 10;
#pragma omp threadprivate(var)
```

(Note, the business to figure out the TLS prefix is taken from [How to declare a variable as thread local portably?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298280/how-to-declare-a-variable-as-thread-local-portably))

I know this works on my system (Debian with recent gcc) but it's hard to know whether things could go wrong elsewhere since these compiler-specific declarations are not part of the OpenMP standard.

Comment: Why don't you first check for the C standard, then for compiler extensions?

Comment: @Olaf I was just matching the way it was suggested in the other SO question I linked. Anyway I don't think it matters at all for the purposes of the question I'm asking here.

Comment: Well, don't follow a pattern if you don't know what it does. It is generally bad design to use extensions if a feature is provided by the standard. Always use the most general way first.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L
# define PREFIX _Thread_local
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
# define PREFIX __thread
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
# define PREFIX __declspec(thread)
#else
# define PREFIX
#endif

PREFIX int var = 10;
#if !PREFIX
#ifdef _OPENMP
#pragma omp threadprivate(var)
#else
#error "Failure to put variable into TLS"
#endif
#endif
```

GCC doesn't mind the over-specifying because `__thread` is an implicit `#pragma omp threadprivate` anyway.

Instead of worrying about compilers where this might not be the case, just use OpenMP's `threadprivate` conditionally.

Comment: Last time I checked `musl` did not work with `gomp`. so if the OP used a standard library other than `glibc` OpenMP might not be available.

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking more about whether there's anything wrong with double-specifying, rather than a way to avoid it with more preprocessor directives.

Comment: @DanRoche I am afraid there is no definite answer for that. It's not specified anywhere what should happen in such a case. Best is to avoid it.